# C++ Multiple definition of helper function

Tags: c++, multiple-definition-error

**EDIT: Answered -- the issue was that because the functions had the same signature, despite them being in separate files, C++ saw both versions and got confused.**

I have three classes: `Table` and `Bed` both inherit from `Furniture`.

`Table` and `Bed` each have a helper function `GetLowerCase(std::string)` defined in each class individually. When `make` is run (Makefile shown below), I get an error saying that `GetLowerCase` in `Bed.cpp` was first defined in `Table.cpp`

Makefile:

```
main: main.o Furniture.o Table.o Bed.o
        g++ main.o Furniture.o Table.o Bed.o -o main

main.o: main.cpp
        g++ -c main.cpp

Furniture.o: Furniture.cpp Furniture.h
        g++ -c Furniture.cpp

Table.o: Furniture.cpp Table.cpp Table.h
        g++ -c Table.cpp

Bed.o: Furniture.cpp Bed.cpp Bed.h
        g++ -c Bed.cpp

clean:
        rm *.o main
```

Table.cpp:

```
#include "Table.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string GetLowerCase(std::string str)
{
        std::string out;
        for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
                out[i] = tolower(str[i]);
        }
        return out;
}

Table::Table(const std::string n, std::string wt) : Furniture(n)
{
        wood_type = GetLowerCase(wt);
        if (wood_type != "pine" && wood_type != "oak")
        {
                std::cerr << "Wood type must be OAK or PINE.";
        }
}

void Table::Print()
{
        Furniture::Print();
        std::cout << "Wood Type: " << wood_type << std::endl;
}
```

Bed.cpp:

```
#include "Bed.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string GetLowerCase(std::string str)
{
        std::string out;
        for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
                out[i] = tolower(str[i]);
        }
        return out;
}

Bed::Bed(const std::string n, std::string sz) : Furniture(n)
{
        size = GetLowerCase(sz);
        if (size != "twin" && size != "full" && size != "queen" && size != "king")
        {
                std::cerr << "Bed size must be TWIN, FULL, QUEEN, or KING.";
        }
}

void Bed::Print()
{
        Furniture::Print();
        std::cout << "Size: " << size << std::endl;
}
```

I would have thought that `GetLowerCase` would be entirely contained within the `.cpp` file it was defined in and wouldn't be "seen" by any other files.

It's not in any header or source files besides the two listed above. Very confused, and would love some help!

Comment: In the whole program there can be only one function with a specific signature, it's done to make it possible to define function in one file and use in the other. If you don't want some function to be visible outside of a specific file, see Crazy Eddie's answer. If you want, then there should be no other function with the same signature which is also visible from outside.

Comment: Regarding makefile: your object files should not depend on other object files. Object files depend on what's required for getting that object file, which is source file and headers; compiler doesn't look at other object files until linking stage.

Comment: By the way, I see that your helper function is the same in both files. I'd suggest moving it to a separate `util.cpp` unit with `util.h` header.

Comment: @yeputons Thanks, I fixed that issue. Working on the Makefile now! Edited the question to reflect what I have right now, but I'm still getting an issue.

Comment: I'd suggest avoid editing the question because it's now completely different. The second issue is that you shouldn't pass `-c` key to `gcc` for linking stage, `-c` means "compile only".

Comment: That worked! Thanks a ton @yeputons. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either declare your function `static` or wrap it in an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace {
    // duplicated names here.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your options:

1. Move all your helper functions into a helper class (like `CommomUtils`) as `static` member functions. I recommend this way, it's more C++, and you can avoid duplicate code.
2. Declare your function as `static`. So its scope would be in file that defines it, rather than global.
3. Warp your function with namespace.
4. Defines your function only once, and in file you want to use it, use `extern std::string GetLowerCase(std::string str)` to declare it, then you can call it.